# Can I assume bash is installed

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I have a cross platform product that gets deployed to several Linux distros and I'm busy changing one of its startup scripts. Currently the script uses /bin/sh as interpreter. My question is. How safe am I if I change this to /bin/bash, will there be some cases that bash is not installed or something. Why does all the scripts in /etc/init.d use /bin/sh. Are there some stuff that will break when using bash?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Can I assume bash is installed

If portability is a goal, you would be doing yourself a disservice to assume `bash` was installed.  That is not to say that `bash` won't be installed 99% of the time, but it's the 1% that gets ya.

> How safe am I if I change this to /bin/bash, will there be some cases that bash is not installed or something

`bash` is a [**POSIX Compliant**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) shell, so unless you need/want to use bash-only syntax, I would not just change the interpreter line to `#!/bin/bash` on a whim; it buys you nothing with a script that works with `#!/bin/sh`

> Why does all the scripts in
>   /etc/init.d use /bin/sh

Because they don't want the system to go down if the admin decides he wants to save hard drive space by deleting `bash` because his favorite shell is `zsh`

> Are there some stuff that will break
>   when using bash?

It's more the other way around. If you have a script with bash-only (non-POSIX) syntax, for example `[[ ]]` or process substitution `<( )`, this will break if you change the interpreter from `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: Also, startup scripts use `sh` because it's faster than Bash.

Comment: On systems where /bin/sh is a link to /bin/bash, even though using /bin/sh runs bash in sh 'compatible' mode it is not completely compatible. It is still possible to use syntax that is bash specific and have it work with /bin/sh linked to bash but not work when using a more strictly compatible shell like dash.

Comment: @Arrowmaster Would you provide specific examples of non-POSIX syntax that bash will execute when run as `/bin/sh`.  Does invoking the shell as `#!/bin/sh --posix` change this behavior?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh Debian and Ubuntu have switched sh from bash to dash, as a result you can find plenty of examples in the changes they have made to sh scripts as a result, they even have a checkbashisms script in their tools to help find them.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how "cross" platform you application is.

In case it runs on "major" linux distributions, feel free to assume bash, but in case of smaller dists, or customized installs bash is not a given. Indeed if you move away from linux i would be even more careful about assuming bash (and for that matter the /bin/bash location is not a given either).

The reason why /etc/init.d scripts always use /bin/sh is because it is a given on most platforms.

I don't think stuff will break if you use bash, bash implements the same "features" as sh, but not the other way around. So in short if you don't need bash specific features, then use /bin/sh

Comment: Yeah, it's often `/usr/bin/bash` (if installed at all) on *BSD, which tend to like ksh more.

Comment: On FreeBSD at least it is `/usr/local/bin/bash` if the package or port was installed without additional options.

Answer (score 1):

To assume that bash is installed falls in the same category as

- All the world's a VAX
- All the CPUs are i386
- All the free Unixen are Linux
- All the IDEs are Eclipse
- All the compilers are gcc

If you keep portability (at least to the POSIX shell) in mind, you **will** save yourself a lot of work for the future. The day will come that you find yourself in a different company, with a different OS and a different shell. Then your knowledge about shell portability will pay large dividends.

The mantra to tell yourself and others is this: "Assumption is the mother of all screw-ups." :-)